# stl model disappears if scale parameter is set in urdf file

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

os: ubuntu 18.04.3
kernel: 4.15-72
rosdistro: ros melodic

Hi, this is a part of my urdf file that works correctly (except the component uses mm as scale so it is zoomed):

```
<link name="base_link">
  <visual>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://nightmare_description/meshes/base_link.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver">
      <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://nightmare_description/meshes/base_link.stl"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>
```

now if I add the scale parameter to this link it completely disappears from rviz although I can see all the axes move correctly:

```
<link name="base_link">
  <visual>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" filename="package://nightmare_description/meshes/base_link.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver">
      <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" filename="package://nightmare_description/meshes/base_link.stl"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>
```

what am I doing wrong? has it something to do with the stl files used?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340553/stl-model-disappears-if-scale-parameter-is-set-in-urdf-file/) by [nikisalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/50113/nikisalli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you tell us what the value is of `LC_NUMERIC`? You can print it using `echo $LC_NUMERIC` in a terminal.

There is a good chance you're running into an issue with `urdf` and locales which use `,` for decimals instead of `.` (ie: comma vs dot).

---

See #q272692 for a related Q&A.

> the output gives `LC_NUMERIC=it_IT.UTF-8`. Should I set the english standard?

As a test, you could see whether the following "solves" your problem:

- open a new terminal
- `export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`
- now source your workspace and try starting RViz again

If your robot -- with the scaling in place -- now does appear, it's most likely [ros/urdfdom_headers#41](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers/issues/41).

If it is `41`, then it should have been fixed recently. According to [this comment on the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/urdfdom-headers/+bug/1817595/comments/23), enabling the `bionic-updates` repository and updating `urdfdom` and `urdfdom-headers` should really fix things (ie: you should not need to use the `LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"` work-around).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nikisalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/50113/nikisalli/) on 2019-12-22**:
the output gives `LC_NUMERIC=it_IT.UTF-8`
should I set the english standard?

**Comment by [nikisalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/50113/nikisalli/) on 2019-12-22**:
i changed the locale but still the model isn't showing up

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-22**:
What did you do exactly? Another test could be to use `,` for the scale, instead of `.`.

**Comment by [nikisalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/50113/nikisalli/) on 2019-12-22**:
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

**Comment by [nikisalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/50113/nikisalli/) on 2019-12-22**:
anyways the whole urdf uses the dot notation and it works as long as I don't set the scaling parameter so the issue should be somewhere else

**Comment by [nikisalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/50113/nikisalli/) on 2019-12-23**:
ok problem solved, you were right! the numeric locale was correctly set to english on the robot but it was set to italian on the host where i was trying to run rviz! after changing my pc's numeric locale to en_US it works flawlessly. thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-23**:
Ok, so as I wrote in my answer, this should have been fixed in Ubuntu itself. Can you check which repositories you have active on the host where you were running RViz? Is the `updates` repository enabled?

You shouldn't need to set all locales to `en_US.UTF-8` any more.

**Comment by [nikisalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/50113/nikisalli/) on 2019-12-23**:
I'm running arch linux on the host

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-23**:
Then you'll have to make sure you're either building a sufficiently new version of those two dependencies, or make sure whatever package repository you are using has the updated versions available.

**Comment by [nikisalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/50113/nikisalli/) on 2019-12-23**:
I updated ros yesterday so probably they haven't fixed the package yet. btw my pc isn't the final pc I'm going to use, I'll use another pc running ubuntu as a controller and map visualizer for the robot so I'll fix this directly on the other pc. thank you for pointing this out!